# Magento : Converting currency before sending data to Google Checkout

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I have a magento site with base currency in USD and Google Checkout in GBP.

> Google Checkout: The currency used in
>   the cart must match the currency of
>   the seller account. You supplied a
>   cart with USD and the seller account
>   is associated with GBP.

Is there a way in magento to convert the amount to GBP before sending to Google Checkout ?
i guess a module could be written to achieve this, but any other workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is far too late, but I hope someone will find this useful.
I don't know how your system works and which version of Magento you are using, but in 1.5 (the one that I am using) in the module GoogleCheckout, look for Model/Api/Xml/Abstract.php, this is base Model for the others models in the GoogleCheckout XML API and it has a method called getCurrency();

```
public function getCurrency()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('currency')) {
       $this->setData('currency', Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode());
        //$this->setData('currency', $this->getLocale()=='en_US' ? 'USD' : 'GBP');
    }
    return $this->getData('currency');
}
```

Since it is not good idea to override Abstract class in PHP [according to this](http://blog.goods-pro.com/1648/how-to-override-abstract-class-in-magento/) you will need to copy this class to the local folder and change the method getCurrency() so it transforms the currency to GBP.